# vector string to string (or c_string) to lpszString

Tags: c++, winapi

(I have some scrabble string manipulating  c++ code which I am trying to run with win32api.)

```
void print_plain_vector_strings(vector<string> S) //works fine

{ 
   for(vector<string>::const_iterator it=S.begin(); it !=S.end(); ++it) 
      cout<<*it<<endl; 
}
```

Questions:

1. How can I rewrite print_plain_vector_strings using printf instead of cout?

   ```
   printf(“%s\n”, *it);  //is the idea
   ```
2. How can I now send *it contents to win32 API using TextOut?

   ```
   TextOut(hdc,x,y,*it,length);  //is the idea
   ```

I expect there has to be an easy way to do this, but, somehow,  I can’t find ANY way.

Comment: You might want to read [a good reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Comment: `printf("%s\n", it->c_str());`

Comment: `it->c_str()` for your first example, and... likewise for the second (assuming you're not compiling unicode *or* you're invoking `TextOutA` directly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [c_str()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) method of `string` returning char* C string:

```
printf(“%s\n”, (*it).c_str());
```

For `TextOut` you need to convert ANSI C string to Unicode. If you work with ANSI only,
you can write:

```
TextOut(hdc, x, y, (*it).c_str(), (*it).length());   // UNICODE is not defined
```

Also, it is better to pass vector by reference, now it is copying each call:

```
void print_plain_vector_strings(const vector<string>& S)
```

Comment: Thanks Alexey, and thanks everyone else ! (That was the first time I have asked a question here, by the way)